# How to use column index when merging?

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pandas, indexing, merge

I would like to merge two csv files and I want to merge them on the first column of the first csv file. Both of the files will have the same column name, but the name is unknown. I do not want to specify a column name for on = ...

What I have:

```
compare = csv1.merge(csv2, on = csv1[csv1.columns[0]] , left_index=True ,right_index = True)
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: It just doesn't work. No error message. Maybe because its not getting the name as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clear what you're trying to do because it looks like you are trying to merge on a specific column, and on indexes. If you want to merge on a specific column, you want "`on`" to accept a string, not a pandas series. So change `on = csv1[csv1.columns[0]]` to `on = csv1.columns[0]` and remove `left_index = True, right_index = True`

If you want to just merge one specific column to csv2, you should do:

```
compare = csv2.merge(csv1[csv1.columns[0]], left_index = True, right_index = True)
```